# Validate the general term formula for series with geometric progression in k-th order differences

Tags: sequences-and-series

The general term $T_r$ of a series with its $k$-th order difference being in G.P. is given by:

$T_r = Aq^r + (\text{Polynomial in } r \text{ of degree 'k-1'})$

Where $r$ is the index of the term, $q$ is the common ratio of the $k$-th order series, and $A$ is a constant.

For example:

For the series $5 + 7 + 13 + 31 + 85 + \ldots$ up to $n$ terms,

The $1$-st order difference series is $2 + 6 + 18 + 54 + \ldots$ (G.P, common ratio q=3)

and hence, by using the formula for the general term (here $k = 1$), we get the general term $T_r = 5 + 3^{(r-1)} - 1$.

Similarly, in this example:

Series: $2 + 4 + 8 + 18 + 46 + 138\ldots$ up to $n$ terms

$1$-st order difference: $2+4+10+28+92+\ldots$

$2$-nd order difference: $2+6+18+54+\ldots$ (G.P, common ratio $q=3$)

Thus, the general term is $(\text{here } k=2)$:

$T_r = (3^r) \cdot \frac{1}{6} + r + \frac{1}{2}.$

When I asked my sir for the proof, he said that the proof is out of our syllabus. However, out of curiosity, I checked rigorously on the internet, but I couldn't find any bit of information about this. Please share your insights and help validate this formula universally.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $G_r = Aq^r$ for some constants $A, q$, then $$\Delta^1 G_r = Aq^{r+1} - Aq^r = A(q-1)q^r$$
(I'm assuming we are talking about forward differences.) This is also a geometric progression, with coefficient $A(q-1)$. So applying the same result $k-1$ more times, $\Delta^k G_r = A(q-1)^kq^r$

So if $\Delta^k T_r = Bq^r$, define the sequence $S_r = T_r - Aq^r$, where $A = \frac B{(q-1)^k}$. Then $$\forall r, \Delta^k S_r = \Delta^k (T_r - Aq^r) = Bq^r - A(q-1)^kq^r = Bq^r - Bq^r = 0$$

Now, if you've covered much of anything about differences, you've probably encountered this theorem:

> If $\Delta^{k+1} a_r = 0$ for all $r$, then $a$ is expressible as a polynomial in $r$ of degree $\le k$. If the $k$-th order difference is not $0$ for all $r$, then the degree of the polynomial is eactly $k$.

But in case you haven't, the theorem follows from the linearity of the $\Delta$ operator, and the fact that $$\Delta^1 r^k = r^{k+1} - r^k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\binom ki r^i$$
I.e., the difference of a polynomial of degree $k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$.

Since $\Delta^k S_r = 0$ for all $r$, it must be a polynomial, and therefore $T_r = Aq^r + S_r$ is of the desired form.